# Inputting values into a 2D array- correctly?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>       

using namespace std;

int main(){

string temp; 
ifstream in("infile.txt");
getline(in, temp);
int dim = temp.length();



char maze [dim-1][dim-1];



int i = 0;
    do{

    for(int l = 0; l<dim; ++l){

        cout<< temp.at(l);
        maze[i][l] = temp.at(l);
        cout << maze[i][l];
    }
    i++;
    cout << endl;

}while(getline(in, temp));


for(int k=0; k<dim; k++){
    for(int m=0; m<dim; m++){
        cout << maze[k][m];
    }
    cout<< endl;
}



cout<< *maze;
}
```

the code reads a block of text assumed to be square and puts each char into a 2d array. it compiles and runs fine, but when I check the values of the array with the final 2 for loops, the last values of each row (ie. maze[0][5], maze[1][5]...) are all wrong. It seems like they have bleeded over to the first character of the next line, but i can't find anything in the code that would do this! Also, even more strangly, the values printed IMMEDIATELY before and immediately after

```
maze[i][l] = temp.at(l);
```

are correct!

What is changing the values in my array?

Comment: Why `char maze [dim-1][dim-1];` ???

Comment: Ahhhh thank you. I got indexing and length mixedup. this completely solved the problem!

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare array with size dim not dim-1 because string has n characters from places 0 to n-1 and null character at n position string.length() returns n.